# clicking events are not working inside my map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a little bit of a problem with my code. my onClick is not working inside the map function not only onClick like onKeyPress, onKeyDown. but other methods are working like onmouseover.

here is my sample  https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-clarke-h1n4u

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Your Code Sandbox example is not running at the moment, making it difficult to debug.

Comment: I fixed it try now.

Comment: Remember to add a `key` if you use map on a JSX component

Answer (score 1):

Please change `onKeyDown` to `onMouseDown` and `selectionHandler` to `() => selectionHandler(arayValue)` like below:

```js
return (
    <DropdownContainer>
      <DropdownInput
        placeholder={"search"}
        onChange={e => setDropValue(e.target.value)}
        value={dropValue}
      />
      <DropdownBlock>
        {array.map(arayValue => (
          <DropDownSpan onMouseDown={() => selectionHandler(arayValue)}>{arayValue}</DropDownSpan>
        ))}
      </DropdownBlock>
    </DropdownContainer>
  );
```

Comment: it's working but why onClick is not working. thanks for answer

Comment: @Ajithkumar `onClick` should also be working fine. Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to get the value to `selectionHandler()`:

```
<DropDownSpan onClick={() => selectionHandler(arayValue)}>{arayValue}</DropDownSpan>
```

You can see it work if you `console.log(value)` in selectionHandler. However, you are currently logging `dropValue` right after you set it using `setDropValue`. Because that update happens asynchronously, the variable may not be set before the `console.log()` is called.

Comment: Here's the working version on Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-water-q6044

Comment: thanks but your code is not working properly.please check it

Comment: I just checked. It's selecting a value from the dropdown and adding it to the state and input field. What more are you expecting?

Comment: I also checked. it's not working for me. please check your codesandbox.

Comment: Still working. Have you tried a new Chrome Incognito window?